# Save KeyErrors and IndexErrors to a list/dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, error-handling, keyerror

I'm trying to extract data from an API, and I expect to receive KeyError and IndexError, so I use the try/except function to catch them. I first create a list of items that I'll loop through to extract information from the API responses. Then I create a dataframe that stores information about items that had no errors.

```
l= ["a","b","c","d"] 
def extract_info_from_one_response(response, idx):
    try:
        response = response.json()
        d = {
            ### some codes ##
            }
    ## ERROR MANAGEMENT
    except KeyError,e:
        print idx, l[idx], str(e)
        return {}
    except IndexError,e:
        print idx, l[idx], str(e)
        return {}
    dat = pd.DataFrame([extract_info_from_one_response(response, idx) for idx, response in enumerate(responses)], index=l)
```

When errors occur, Python prints out [1]the index of the problematic item, [2] the name of the item and [3]the details on the error that took place. How do I save/capture these three outputs, save them into objects or create a dataframe with these 3 pieces of information?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking, but if you want to save what is printed:

```
key_err = []
idx_err = []

def extract_info_from_one_response(response, idx):
   try:
     # your code here
   except KeyError, e:
       key_err.append((idx, l[idx], '{}'.format(e),))
       return {}
   except IndexError, e:
       idx_err.append((idx, l[idx], '{}'.format(e),))
       return {}
   # your normal code here
   # you need to return something here
dat = pd.DataFrame([extract_info_from_one_response(response, idx) for idx, response in enumerate(responses)], index=l)
print(key_err)
print(idx_err)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Three things. [1] I tried the code you suggested, and I got the an error. Turns out 'continue' can only be used in a 'for' or a 'while' loop. [2] Also, after the function finishes, I cannot print key_err or idx_err since these two items "died" as the function exits. [3]. I believe the pd.Dataframe line only works if I return {} under the exceptions. I can't return key_err or idx_err. Thank you for your help

Comment: key_err and idx_err do not die after the function (unless you put them inside the function definition).  You also need to make sure your dat line is outside the function body (see my edit).

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to trace the error?

If so,the traceback module would help like this:

```
In [1]: import traceback

In [2]: try:
   ...:     a = []
   ...:     a[2] = 1
   ...: except Exception:
   ...:     y = traceback.format_exc()
   ...:     

In [4]: print y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-2-ac34fe2721d3>", line 3, in <module>
    a[2] = 1
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```